# How to use ES query with offset+limit >1000

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an API exposed for my client where I am using ES to fetch data for specific time range. The number is records is well over 1 million. Now, I had to provide another feature where I give them offset and limit where the client can fetch number of records(limit) from the offset.

My ES query is formed like

`{"from":10000,"size":2001,"timeout":"60s","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"tollId":["59850"],"boost":1.0}},{"range":{"updatedAt":{"from":"2020-08-15T00:00:00.000Z","to":null,"include_lower":true,"include_upper":true,"boost":1.0}}},{"range":{"updatedAt":{"from":null,"to":"2020-12-15T22:08:21.000Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":true,"boost":1.0}}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"sort":[{"updatedAt":{"order":"desc"}}]}`

When I execute this on Elastic Search, I get

```
"failed_shards": [
{
  "shard": 0,
  "index": "companydatabase",
  "node": "vQU6NjSVRK6dKNLsWkfqEw",
  "reason": {
  "type": "query_phase_execution_exception",
  "reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [12001]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."
}
```

The solution is to use Scroll API to fetch the records but I cant use scroll Api when I have to fetch records from some offset to some limit.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to tackle this or I will have to get all the records(documents) everytime and filter the result?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your index settings `max_result_window` to something higher, the default is `10000`. So for example, if you did a from + size under 10000 it would work fine, anything over you need to change your `max_result_window` for that index:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:4200/the_index/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 500000 } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Obviously using scroll API for ES will make this more efficient alternative to raising this.

Comment: @Dharman  That is one solution. But as I told you the number of records are more than 1 million. Wont't it impact my API's performance?

Comment: it takes more heap and memory + time depending on the from + size total so in short yes. You should be using the scroll API but if your server has enough memory it will be ok for the short term. Either do not let the client go so far as 9999 and request reports for anything past 10000 or change your logic to use the scroll API.

Comment: Thanks. I somewhat knew that Scroll API is going to be my last resort but eventually bringing so many records and filtering them on the basis of offset and limit will again have an impact on my heap.